# Does using a dual-bladed weapon count as Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: feats, weapons, two-weapon-fighting, star-wars-d20

This is a little roundabout... I started playing Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic (not the MMO) out of nostalgia, and I noticed *for the first time* that it's actually based on a D20 system - in particular, the Star Wars flavor.

I'm planning on dual-wielding, so I've picked up the feat chain Two Weapon Fighting. Since I was a kid I had always assumed dual-bladed melee weapons (lightsabers, vibroswords) counted as "two weapons" for the sake of this feat. However, I recently brought this up to my friends and they acted like I was crazy.

Given that it's a pretty old game and that I never played the D20 Star Wars system, could someone help me out here? Does the Two Weapon Fighting feat count towards dual-bladed weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.  Using a dual-bladed weapon without substantial penalties requires the Two-Weapon Fighting feat in SWD20.  The rulebook specifically mentions it in the case of dual-bladed lightsabers, noting that the off-hand blade counts as a light weapon for calculating the penalties.

Comment: Technically it isn't *required*, but without it you take pretty ridiculous penalties to your attack rolls.

Comment: That "required" bit was confusing me, cause in the games it's not required either.

Comment: Good point.  I'll edit my answer to reflect that.